# Problem with object declaration/initialization as a private member on a different class

Tags: c++, class, object, initialization, declaration

Sorry if this has been asked before, I can't seem to find anything. I'm not sure how to search for this.

I have something like this:

```
class A {
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    public:
        A(int, int);
}

class B {
    private:
        A a(3, 4); // Doesn't compile because of this line
    public:
        B();
}
```

The only way I could think to solve this was making `a` a pointer to `A` and then do `a = new A(3, 4);` inside `B`'s constructor. But I don't want `a` to be a pointer.

What's the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Are all your defined types simple POD-like integral types? If so you could create them as non-type template parameters. eg. `A<3, 4> a;`. There are constrains to this approach though, one being those init values must be known at compile-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tag `B`'s constructor with a "member initialization list". Instead of:

```
B::B() {
    ...
}
```

You do this:

```
B::B() : a(3, 4) {
    ...
}
```

Or if the constructor is defined in the header:

```
class B {
    private:
        A a;
    public:
        B() : a(3, 4) {
            ...
        }
};
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way? What if I had dozens of variables to initialize? The code would look really weird.

Comment: @Nazgulled: C++ does look weird, if you aren't familiar with it. It's not actually a problem until you have dozens of data members *and* more than one constructor.

Comment: @Nazgulled: C++ looks weird. That's part of the language. *Get over it.* That said, if you really hate the syntax, and `class A` has a default constructor, it will be used automatically; you can then assign a new value to `a` (`a = A(3, 4);`) in the constructor, but that's inefficient. Better to use the initialization list where possible as it can be better-optimized and produce smaller/faster code.

Comment: Can I assume that that would be the same as declaring a `setVals` method to be used in `B`'s constructor as `a.setVals(3,4);`? Which is also inefficient?

Comment: That plus the cost of actually replacing the contents of `a` with the contents of the temporary instance of `A`. If you haven't defined an assignment operator for `A`, then that's essentially a call to `memcpy()`--if you have, it's the cost of that method. The total cost of doing `a = A(3, 4)` will thus vary based on the actual type of `class A`. *Just get over your distaste of the syntax and use the initialization list. It will do exactly what you need and is the proper way to initialize fields in C++.*

Comment: I was converting my current code to use classes instead, so another solution is to forget that idea for now. :P

Answer (score 2):

```
class B {
    private:
        A a;
    public:
        B() : a(3,4) {}
};
```

In a wider sense, the solution is to learn C++ by [reading a book about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Yes, that's snarky, but the point of tutorials is that they introduce concepts in a sensible order, and when they tell you about data members they will simultaneously tell you how to initialize them.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is for B.a to be initialized with the arguments 3 and 4, then you do that in B's constructor, e.g.,

```
class B {
    private:
        A a;
    public:
        B(): a(3, 4) {}
}
```